# VueJs 2.x stylebind with object with multiple keys not working

Tags: binding, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm fiddling around with vue for the first time and having troubles with getting `v-bind:style="styleObject"` getting to work properly. It works when styleObject only has one key/value-pair in it, but nothing comes when I have more than 1 key/value-pair.

When running `console.log()` the values comes out as they should.

My vue code:

```
<script>
import Vue from 'vue';
import ImageObject from './SkyCropImage.class';

export default Vue.component('sky-crop', {
    props: {
        src: String,
        focalpoint: String,
        mode: String,
        round: String,
        type: {
            type: String,
            default: 'img',
        },
    },
    data() {
        return {
            image: new ImageObject(this.src),
            srcString: '',
            styleObject: { },
        };
    },
    methods: {
        anchorString(image) {
            if (this.$el.firstChild.localName !== 'img') {
                this.styleObject.backgroundPosition = `${image.anchor.x} ${image.anchor.y}`;
            } else {
                const pointX = (image.anchor.x.replace('%', '') * 1) / 100;
                const pointY = (image.anchor.y.replace('%', '') * 1) / 100;

                const differenceX = image.parent.width - image.calculatedInfo.width;
                const differenceY = image.parent.height - image.calculatedInfo.height;

                const anchorX = Math.min(0, differenceX * pointX);
                const anchorY = Math.min(0, differenceY * pointY);

                this.styleObject.transform = `translate(${anchorX}px, ${anchorY}px)`;
            }
        },
        concatSrc(string) {
            this.srcString = string;

            if (this.type !== 'img') {
                this.styleObject.backgroundImage = `url(${string})`;
            }
        },
    },
    created() {
        this.image.mode = this.mode;
        this.image.round = this.round;
        this.image.anchor = {
            x: this.focalpoint.split(',')[0],
            y: this.focalpoint.split(',')[1],
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        this.image.setParentInfo(this.$el);
        this.image.runCropJob();
        this.anchorString(this.image);
        this.concatSrc(this.image.outputUrl);
    },
});
```

My template:

```
<div class="skyCrop-parent">
<img
    class="skyCrop-element"
    alt=""
    v-if="type === 'img'"
    v-bind:src="srcString" 
    v-bind:style="styleObject" />
// img result: <img alt="" src="https://source.unsplash.com/Ixp4YhCKZkI/700x394" class="skyCrop-element" style="transform: translate(-50px, 0px);">

<div 
    class="skyCrop-element"
    v-bind:style="styleObject"
    v-else>
</div>
//div result: <div class="skyCrop-element"></div>

</div>
```

How the component is called:

```
<sky-crop
    src="https://source.unsplash.com/Ixp4YhCKZkI/1600x900"
    focalpoint="50%,50%"
    mode="width"
    round="175"
    type="div">
</sky-crop>

<sky-crop
    src="https://source.unsplash.com/Ixp4YhCKZkI/1600x900"
    focalpoint="50%,50%"
    mode="width"
    round="175">
</sky-crop>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug lies in the way Vue handles reactivity.

Since I tried to add key/value pair to `styleObject` like this:

```
this.styleObject.backgroundPosition = `${image.anchor.x} ${image.anchor.y}`;
```

Vue could not detect the change since the keys i tried to reference was not declare beforehand. The solution could be defining all future could be keys, which would work just fine. However using `vm.$set()` would be better since it handles creating the key and initiates the reactivity at the same time. In short this line (and the others which did the same):

```
this.styleObject.backgroundPosition = `${image.anchor.x} ${image.anchor.y}`;
```

Became this:

```
this.$set(this.styleObject, 'background-position', `${image.anchor.x} ${image.anchor.y}`);
```

Vue documentation about the reason for the change:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html